# Default Request options in angular2 rc5

Tags: angular

Before the new `NgModule` I used to to extend the `RequestOptions` using a custom class and added it in `bootstrap`

```
class MyOptions extends RequestOptions {
  constructor() {
    let token = getCookie("hyper-token");
    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
        }
        return "";
    }
    let startedAt = getCookie('start');
    super({
        headers: new Headers({
            'Authorization': "token " + token,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        })
    });
  }
}
```

and then

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [{ provide: RequestOptions, useClass: MyOptions}])
```

How can I do this is rc.5 with new `NgModule`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use something like that:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: RequestOptions, useClass: MyOptions} // <-----
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and bootstrap the module this way:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: Hi Thierry. I have tried `{ provide: RequestOptions, useClass: MyOptions}` to no avail on my RC5 app. Can you confirm that this syntax does work with the new `@NgModule` from RC5? It is documented nowhere unfortunately and I can't find the proper way to provide an "inline provider" as above.

Comment: By the way my `useClass` key points to a subclass of `BaseRequestOptions` and I get a cryptic *Cannot read property 'toString' of null*